# Program disappear in Release mode but work fine with Beep(0,0) inserted

Tags: c++

The program works fine under a Debugger (even in release mode) so I have to insert Beep(500,200) to find out the last spot that it fails. I narrow it down to a thread proc that call CreateProcess(). If the Beep is inserted after the call the program would vanish without sound, but if the Beep is inserted before: it beeps and continues without error.

To prevent the annoying beep, I replace it with Beep(0,0) and has been happy. I did try with Sleep(0) but that does not work.

I used to work as a Lisp programmer and has some similar experiences: inserting (princ "debug") until I locate the spot then replacing it with (princ)

The question is why?

Comment: Any (minimal piece of) code you could share with us that exhibits the problems you're experiencing?

Comment: The question is why... Why what? Why you had some similar experiences in Lisp? Why you used to insrt print "debug"? :)

Comment: you can say more about you ide and compiler

Comment: Does anything get logged into the EventLog?

Answer (score 0):

From your naming conventions i think you are using *Visual Studio* but you don't say this (you can add information about this, will help).

If you are using *Visual Studio* you can debug program compiled in release mode, you must only **attach to his process** and you can start setting some breakpoints, **beep's to debug is not effective** because you must compile program again when you want set/change your "checkpoint" and you can't propertly debug stack corruption problems and can't review stack !

Comment: I wonder which naming convention pointed you to VS. Clearly he's talking about windows, but why do you think it's VS?

Comment: The first sentence of the question says he ran it in a debugger in release mode...

Comment: Also, beeps may effect the execution timing of your program.